# Name of input file in replacement output of stream editor?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a list of files to pass to sed:

```
echo abc > test0; echo cab > test1; echo xyz > test2
```

I need to have a group captured *and* the filename in the output of sed like

```
$ cat test0 test1 test2 | sed -E 's/(\b[abc]+\b)/found \1 in file \?/'
found abc in file ?
found cab in file ?
xyz
```

with the question marks replaced by the respective filenames. is that even possible? if yes, how :D

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I know I can have that by simply

```
grep -E '(\b[abc]+\b)' test0 test1 test2
```

but I really need my own output to generate code in another language

Comment: do you know what does your `cat|sed` line do?

Comment: In your particular structure, `sed` has no idea about file names because it's reading from an unnamed pipe. `cat` takes the contents of all three files and creates the appearance of a single unnamed file containing the con-`cat`-enation of the three files. Even using `sed ... test0 test1 test2`, most versions of `sed` have no way to get at the current file name. You could use either `awk` or a simple loop over the files, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a loop. You can use this with bash:

```
for i in test0 test1 test2; do 
    sed -E "s/(\b[abc]+\b)/found \1 in file $i/" "$i"
done
```